# How to use <a> tag to change <div> box color

Tags: html, css

I'm new to css and html. I want to have a button that could change the color of the div box. I tried using pseudo classes, but it doesnt seem to be working. Here is the sample of the code. How can I make it so when you click the link, it changes the color of the div box.

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
}
p {
    display: inline-block;
}
.link1 {
    background-color: #002147;
    border: 2px #002147;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 1.17em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
div {
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    font-size: 1.17em;
}
a.link1:visited .box1 {
    background-color: #008080;
    border: 2px #0e8080;
    color: #ffd700;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>1 Button, 1 Box</title>
   </head>
    <body>
        <p><a class="link1" href="#box1">First Link</a></p>
        <div class="box1">Div 1 here</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use same id as href, and in css use :target on the id, example:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
}
p {
    display: inline-block;
}
.link1 {
    background-color: #002147;
    border: 2px #002147;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 1.17em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
div {
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    font-size: 1.17em;
}
#box1:target {
    background-color: #008080;
    border: 2px #0e8080;
    color: #ffd700;
}
```

```html
<p><a class="link1" href="#box1">First Link</a></p>
<div id="box1">Div 1 here</div>
```

Comment: `label` is meant to describe an associated form element. Don't abuse it for purposes out-of-scope for this element.

Comment: Thank you! But I've encountered some problems when I used this for multiple links and divs. When I click the link, it changes the style of multiple divs. I want to make it like clicking the first link changes the style of first div, second link to second div and so on.

Comment: First things first, absolutely agreeing with connexo, but it's more harmful to abuse the a tag for something like this.
And regarding your question Ray, you need new input fields, same as you planned i guess, with .link1 add a class to the input link1, link2 or what ever and you will bind them.

Comment: @zeljkoDe No, that is one of the purposes the `a` element is designed for (linking to a specific part of the page).

Comment: From what i gathered, there is no need for linking anything, only styling update. But I may be wrong...

Comment: It's supposed to be a link that changes the style of the div

Comment: Oh, my bad then, then go with :target

Comment: @Ray i updated the answer, change class to id (or add next to it) and i css use #....:target

Comment: You haven't updated your explanation.

Answer (score 2):

With JS. Assign a eventListner to your link. Then create a function which add add a class with a background-color. You can also set style attribute with javascript.

**Like that:**

```js
function change() {
  const div = document.querySelector('.box1');  
  div.classList.toggle('red-bg');
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
}
p {
    display: inline-block;
}
.link1 {
    background-color: #002147;
    border: 2px #002147;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 1.17em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
div {
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    font-size: 1.17em;
}
a.link1:visited .box1 {
    background-color: #008080;
    border: 2px #0e8080;
    color: #ffd700;
}

a.link1 {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.red-bg {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>1 Button, 1 Box</title>
   </head>
    <body>
        <p><a class="link1" onclick="change()">First Link</a></p>
        <div class="box1">Div 1 here</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `:target` selector. Something like so:

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Arial", sans-serif;
}
p {
    display: inline-block;
}
.link1 {
    background-color: #002147;
    border: 2px #002147;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 1.17em;
    text-decoration: none;
}
div {
    width: 150px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    font-size: 1.17em;
}
 

.box1:target{
   background-color: #008080;
    border: 2px #0e8080;
    color: #ffd700;
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>1 Button, 1 Box</title>
   </head>
    <body>
        <p><a class="link1" href="#box1">First Link</a></p>
        <div class="box1" id ="box1">Div 1 here</div>
    </body>
</html>
```